# Attempting to populate Multiselect button default options based on persistent st.session_state (maintaining sidebar selections through multiple pages)

Tags: python-3.x, multi-select, session-state, streamlit

- We're using the sidebar to filter a Pandas DataFrame.
- The user settings need to persist, and be editable, on a bunch of different pages
- st.sidebar is it's own Streamlit page
- And calling it from different streamlit pages resets all the variables and settings if they are local to the page only.

To try and keep the selections appearing in the sidebar persistent, I'm attempting to use `st.session_state` to manage the settings. However, A Multiselect box is causing a problem with this, because it does not actually set the persistent `session_state` variable until ***after*** a page reload...so the persistent `session_state` variable used to set the Multiselect's default options always lags behind by one selection.

I've created a kluge where the page checks to see if the multiselect options have changed, and ***does a second page reload***, however this means every selection takes two page reloads instead of one - which slows everything down.

***Q1: Is there a way around the double-page reloads?***

***Q2: Is there a better way to make selections in the sidebar persist amongst many pages?***

***(See code below pictures)***
***(In pictures 'LOCAL' == 'st.session_state)***

1. Without kluge, before any selection made...

[image]

2. Select a project and the ***page reloads***, but notice printing out the session_state variable above the Multiselect still shows no selection. The one immediately after shows variable as set.

[image]

3. Select a new options (1290) ... and thre selection is lost, because the session_state variable is only now available to the page and, because the session_state var is used for defaults, the defaults are reset to the previous selection

[image]

5. Do the identical selection ***again***, and it remains.

[image]

***example page in streamlit_home/pages***

```
from sidebar import persistent_sidebar 
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")
st.header("My example Streamlit page with persistent sidebar")
local_df = persistent_sidebar()
<does other stuff using local_df and variables set in session_state)
```

***streamlit_home/sidebar.py code***

```
def persistent_sidebar():
    with st.sidebar:
        _df = st.session_state["immutable_df"]
        
        # Initialize variable for first run (where key "_selected_options" doesnt yet exist)
        # This is the variable for olding the persistent Multiselect selections                                   
        try: st.session_state["_selected_options"]
        except KeyError: 
            st.session_state["_selected_options"] = []

        # Get all the possible options that will appear    
        _options = sorted(list(_df[<filter_on_column>].unique())) 

        # Write out what options are already persisting
        # This lags behind the actual selection     
        st.write('st.session_state["_selected_options"]:', st.session_state["_selected_options"]) #333

        container = st.container()

        # _options are all the possible Options
        # _defaults are the options that had been selected from previous page loads
        # Setting it into a separate, non-persistent var is part of the kluge fix
        _defaults = st.session_state["_selected_options"]

        # Actual multiselect button
        st.session_state["_selected_options"] = container.multiselect("", 
            _options, # All options
            _defaults, # Options already appearing as selected by default
            key='sidebar_persistent_filter_container_multiselect')

        # Write out what options are in var immediately after selecting
        # The page (sidebar) does a reload immediately after selecting a selection in the multiselect button 
        # This st.write shows the session_state variable has already been modified
        # However, the page load is what actually sets the session_state variable so
        #  the st.session_state["_selected_options"] var ABOVE the Multiselect
        #  lags behind by one selection       
        st.write('st.session_state["_selected_options"]=', st.session_state["_selected_options"])#333

        #===========================================================================
        # Calling a second page load means the st.session_state["_selected_options"]
        #  is now set before the Multiselect box, but it slows the page down by requiring two page reloads  
        #  if _defaults != st.session_state["_selected_options"]:
        #     st.experimental_rerun()
        #===========================================================================

        <filter _df with selections>

        return _df
```

Comment: Where are you updating session state after the multiselect value changes? Also what's the purpose of "session_statest"?

Comment: The `session_statest` was a typo from cutting and pasting in the code to stack. I.e. the word ``st.session_state` repeated twice (st.session_statest.session_state) Sorry about that. Thanks for pointing it out to me. The session_state variable is updated by the mutiselect itself. I.e. `st.session_state["_selected_options"] = container.multiselect(...)` I have tried having the multiselect store in a temp local variable, I.e. `var = container.multiselect(...); st.session_state["_selected_options"] = var`, but that had no effect at all.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this code would actually update the value of the session state variable, since it's just being defined once and not updated. I would think that you would want to have an `on_change` function that gets called whenever someone interacts with the multiselect which would then update the value of the session state variable.

Comment: @CarolineFrasca It does seem to actually update the session_state variable, but I have to refresh the page twice to do it. I.e. When something is selected in `st.session_state["_selected_options"] = container.multiselect(...)` the multiselect then does a page refresh, after which the session_state variable is updated. However, because (on that first refresh) the multiselect itself uses that session_state var to determine it's "currently selected" contents - the change is not reflected. If I force a second refresh, the multiselect then shows values from the session_state var.

Comment: Hey @RightmireM, I did some digging and this is indeed a bug that we are working on! You can view the GitHub Issue for it here: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/6074  However wanted to share that one of our community members came up with a workaround for the meantime, which she shared here: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/mini-tutorial-initializing-widget-values-and-getting-them-to-stick-without-double-presses/31391/4